# Java: Finding an item in a list by its name using a for loop

Tags: java, arraylist

SO I started a Java class, but it has been a slog.  The teacher won't let us use anything but the book, but that has proven an impossible since a lot of the assignments in the class he gives don't even give us assignments that mirror what's in the book, he just says "figure it out", which is BS for an introduction class for Java.

Ok, with my venting done (sorry), I'll try and outline the assignment problem I'm having at the moment without posting the actual assignment.

We are working with just 1 class from a set of classes making up a "store".

The first part of the actual work in this premade class is to find an item by it's name and then return the item with the name or null if there is no item by that name.

The only hint that the assignment gives is to use a for each to go over each item in the list we have.

Below is the method of code I have to fill the inside of.

```
public Item findItem(String name)
{

}
```

My list of items is (item type, description, cost, number of):

```
public void populateItems()
{
 addItem(new Item("knife", "Bread", 11.99, 1));
}
```

After this are the next 4 problems I have to code all on my own, so I'll note them below.

- A method to removeItem.  My "hint" is ArrayList has a  remove method, use findItem to the item to remove and pass it to remove.
- A method called getItemByType takes a String param and returns a list of items by their type. My "hint" is the structure of this will be the same as the that of a certain past project.
- A method called getNumOfItem, that returns the max number of items in the store.  So if there is 1 bread knife and 0 steak knives then the max would be 1.
- Final method is to be called printItemSummaryStats. This prints off all the stats of the items in the store (item type, description, etc.)

I know that this is vague, but I'm hoping folks could give me some easy examples of how I can code my own answers to these problems.

Please keep in mind that I don't understand anything complex.  I am a beginner, just learning about Java, so if a method is kind of long, but easy to follow for a noob like me then please post it.

Comment: your Item class doesn't have any property called 'name' to find item by name. did you mean description is equal name? can you please clarify it?

Comment: The class for the project would be "ItemStore."  The above parts are methods inside the ItemStore class.  So "name" wouldn't be a class but a parameter in the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find an item in the list by it's name, you have to iterate through all the items and check if any item's name is equal to name you search (i assume name is string, and you have getter to it in your `Item` class)
Lets assume that you keep all items in `ArrayList` named `arrayListItems`:

```
public Item findItem(String name)
{
   for(Item item : arrayListItems){
      if(item.getName().equals(name){
         return item;
      }
   }
   return null;
}
```

In your second problem you'll have to check if `ArrayList` contains item you search, and if it does, remove it and return value saying that item has been found and removed:

```
public boolean removeItem(Item item){
   arrayListItems.remove(item); //this method return boolean value 
}
```

In third problem iterate through all items and add them to the new `ArrayList`, then remove it.

```
public ArrayList<Item> getItemByType(String type){
   ArrayItem<Item> arrayListFilteredItems = new ArrayList<>();

   for(Item item : arrayListItems){
      if(item.getType().equals(type){
         arrayListFilteredItems.add(item);
      }
   }

   return arrayListFilteredItems;
}
```

Next problems are also really easy if you think what to do step by step. I won't solve all your problem, to not make it so easy :D

Comment: Thank you, this is the type of help I was hoping to receive.  I only hope that to see additional ways of how these methods can be written.  I'm not sure if there is just one proper way of how these must be written or other ways.